# Oracle error 00979

Tags: sql, oracle

Getting an error code for the following

```
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, ASSIGN_ID, ASSIGN_COMP, SOFTWARE.SFT_ID, COUNT(SFT_TITLE)
FROM EMPLOYEE, ASSIGN_PC, SOFTWARE
WHERE EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID = ASSIGN_PC.ASSIGN_EMP
GROUP BY SFT_TITLE
```

It runs fine when I take out the count and group by commands but I can't get it to run otherwise.  Any help is appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use explicit `join` syntax.  Second, you need to aggregate by all the columns that are not arguments to the aggregation functions:

```
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, ASSIGN_ID, ASSIGN_COMP, SOFTWARE.SFT_ID, COUNT(SFT_TITLE)
FROM EMPLOYEE JOIN
     ASSIGN_PC
     ON EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID = ASSIGN_PC.ASSIGN_EMP CROSS JOIN
     SOFTWARE
GROUP BY EMP_ID, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, ASSIGN_ID, ASSIGN_COMP, SOFTWARE.SFT_ID;
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of this query is, but it sure looks like it is missing a `join` condition to the `software` table.  My guess is that you really want something like:

```
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, ASSIGN_ID, ASSIGN_COMP, SOFTWARE.SFT_ID, COUNT(SFT_TITLE)
FROM EMPLOYEE JOIN
     ASSIGN_PC
     ON EMPLOYEE.EMP_ID = ASSIGN_PC.ASSIGN_EMP JOIN
     SOFTWARE
     ON ASSIGN_PC.SFT_ID = SOFTWARE.SFT_ID
GROUP BY EMP_ID, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, ASSIGN_ID, ASSIGN_COMP, SOFTWARE.SFT_ID;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon thanks for your input.  The purpose of the query is to show a count of the number of installations for each software title.  I am getting an 00904 error when running your second set of commands.  The first set is working well.  Thanks for your help!